# Flash player for website written in HTML4

Tags: html, flash, html4

I would like to put a flash movie with **.swf**  format in my website, so I need a flash player that runs inside the browsers.
I found something like [flowplayer](http://www.flowplayer.org), but it seems it works with HTML5. I need a free flash player for HTML4.

Do you know something to suggest ?

Comment: Can't you just embed the swf directly? There are Flash plugins for all major browsers.

Comment: Can I have play, pause, stop controls in this way?

Comment: Ah, no, I don't think so. I guess I misunderstood your question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using [jw player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players) and embed mode :)